# ngx.status variable not being set

Tags: nginx, lua

In my nginx config I have the following lines set up to serve a fallback error page from lua:

```
error_page 502 @fallback;

location @fallback {
     content_by_lua_file 'fallback.lua';
}

location / {
    return 502;
}
```

Then in my lua file, I have the following at the top of the file:

```
ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "reported status is: " .. ngx.status)
```

I expect it to be 502 but this reports that ngx.status is 0.

I've tried to fix this by writing

```
set $status 502
```

but nginx complains that `$status` is a duplicate of an existing variable and won't load the config.

How can I get lua to know about the nginx status from a return directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in ngx_lua. Response status code for the "return" directive is stored diffrently than normal response status code, that is, in `r->err_status` rather than `r->headers_out.status`. The `ngx.status` API just read the latter rather than the former.

This issue was already fixed in ngx_lua's master branch as commit 82ba941d:

https://github.com/chaoslawful/lua-nginx-module/commit/82ba941d

This fix will be included in the next release of ngx_lua (0.9.1) and ngx_openresty (1.4.3.1).

Thank you for the report!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in the lua module was preventing this from being set properly.

https://github.com/chaoslawful/lua-nginx-module/commit/82ba941d